# is there such thing as PHP PDL?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Ok, i had a phone interview yesterday and they told me to prepare for a face interview and told me to learn something called PHP PDL. when i googled PHP PDL nothing seems to come up and my phone for some reason didnt save the number to call them back. So now i have 1 day left before the interview and want to know what to prepare for, i do know PHP but what is PDL, they mentioned something about SQL injections and prepared statements that PDL is a good way to use it. Maybe i misheard it and it was something different like pdl or gdl i dont know. Please if anyone knows what it can be respond.

Again its related to PHP and has some connection to SQL injections and prevention of it using prepared statements.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would imagine it was PDO rather than PDL.

[php.net : PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

[php.net : PDO Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: thank you i think thats the one i just read it, its a way to connect to the database right, i remember him saying that. Is there any good video tutorials for it or will i be able to learn within 3-4 hours? i need to know basics of it

Comment: Personally I think the php.net documentation covers what you need to know. Here's a tutorial though http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/ a quick google will get you tons of results

Comment: Yes I think you'll get the hang of it within three hours, depends how quick you are a learning things though :) It's not too dissimilar to what you're probably used to.